# Mule ESB, formatting decimal format from expression node

Tags: json, expression, mule, esb

Prevously I had a result from a Database Connection SQL statement that resembled the following:

```
[{"BALANCE":111.11},{"BALANCE":222.12},{"BALANCE":444.30}]
```

And I used the following contents of an expression node to calculate the sum:

```
sum = 0;
foreach (row : message.payload) {
  sum += row['BALANCE'];
}
message.payload = sum;
```

This did not quite work out, but notice below that there are no quotes around the numeric variable that was returned

```
777.5299999999999994315658113919199
```

From an excellent answer from a previous thread, I switched to the following expression node contents:

```
sum = 0;
foreach (row : message.payload) {
  sum += row['BALANCE'];
}
message.payload = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.##").format(sum);
```

This resulted the accurate result below:

```
"777.53"
```

My only problem is that it has quotes around the number.  How can I eliminate the quotes?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a string or a number? If a number, the first solution is correct. If a string, the second one is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real fix to your problem is the following: **do not use floating point numbers to store currency amounts**. This is prone to rounding errors (as you've experienced above) and it turns out people don't like to lose cents here and there.

Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/3730040/387927 for more on this.

So fix the database to store only integers, for example in cents, `111111` instead of `111.11`, and only perform integer calculations on these cents.

Or review the DB query to return `java.math.BigDecimal` instances instead of the `floats` or `doubles` it seems to be returning. That way you would have no adverse rounding playing tricks on you.

Any other approach where you first would go through a lossy floating point data type and then perform rounding (like in user1760178's answer), will expose you to rounding issues.

Answer (score 1):

You may try converting the sum to BigDecimal and then set scale on it to 2.

```
message.payload = new BigDecimal(sum).setScale(2,java.math.RoundingMode.CEILING)
```

This keeps your payload as number instead of a String.

Hope this helps.